# redux-persist blacklist not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I want to blacklist some of my reducers because my state tree is getting bigger and im getting this error:

> Could not write debug session to localStorage: DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'redux-persist' exceeded the quota.(…)"

The solution I found is to blacklist some reducers that doesn't need to be persisted. So I have this code in my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { Initializer } from './components';
import store from './store';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { rehydrated: false }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    persistStore(store, { blacklist: ['project', 'comment', 'project', 'jobOrder']}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    }) 
  }

render() {
    if(!this.state.rehydrated)
      return <Initializer />;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              ... some Routes
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and I have this `rootReducer`:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userAuthReducer from './userAuthReducer';
import jobOrderReducer from './jobOrderReducer';
import clientReducer from './clientReducer';
import userReducer from './userReducer';
import persistReducer from './persistReducer';
import commentReducer from './commentReducer';
import projectReducer from './projectReducer';
import teamReducer from './teamReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    userAuth: userAuthReducer,
    jobOrder: jobOrderReducer,
    job_order: jobOrderReducer,
    client: clientReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    persist: persistReducer,
    comment: commentReducer,
    project: projectReducer,
    team: teamReducer
});
```

My `persistReducer.js`

```
import { PERSIST } from '../actions/types';

export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PERSIST:
            return { ...state, ...action.payload }
        default:
            return state;   
    }
};
```

And my `store.js`

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
//import logger from 'redux-logger';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    {}, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk, /*logger*/), 
        autoRehydrate())
    );

//persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

But running the App, I still get the blacklisted persisted state as you can see here:

[image: logs of persisted state]

I tried changing the blacklist keys to:

```
persistStore(store, { blacklist: ['reduxPersist:project', 'reduxPersist:comment', 'reduxPersist:project', 'reduxPersist:jobOrder']}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
```

But the keys are still persisting... How to properly do this?

Comment: Did you clear the `localStorage` in your browser after changing the code ?

Comment: Yes but upon clearing and reloading the page again it still persists..

Comment: this is weird...

Answer (score 1):

I read this [article](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/41221688-the-example-usage-of-whitelist-and-blacklist-in-docs-causes-confusion) here and the author made a good point, the blacklist isn't looking for the name of the attributes in your redux store, rather in your state. I had the same confusion.

Double check in dev tools what is actually being saved in your local storage. make sure you are blacklisting the correct names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `blacklist` array in both config objects (parent and child).

```
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ['appReducer'], // 2: Need to add child reducer key here too.
};

const appPersistConfig = {
  key: 'appReducer',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  // 1: Below are the keys to blacklist
  blacklist: ['snackbar', 'dayThought', 'updatingBohoId', 'snackbar_notif'], 
};
```

Comment: Thank you this is the solution for me, add child reducer is what I was missing!